# Insert data from one table into another while also inserting values not associated with a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry for the post I am very new to this and only have one other post.

So I am sure someone is going to link to another file here that I wasn't able to find and I have seen the `INSERT INTO * SELECT` option. The problem I am having is that I need to add values from both an already created table and values from  user input into a table. I would like to do this in one statement using SQL if possible.

aka

I have a table that has values

name, product_id, qty,

and user input

date, ccn, billing, shipping, status

I want to add both the user input and the table values into a new table

Answer (score 1):

You would usually use `insert . . .  select`:

```
insert into destination_table (name, product_id, qty, date, ccn, billing, shipping, status)
    select name, product_id, qty, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
    from source_table;
```

The `?` are placeholders for the parameters that hold the user input values.